# How to Control Width of Title (H2) with CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've tried the CSS below. All of the other specifications are working except the width. You can see an example of the  being too wide [here](http://www.glamourunderground.com/551/skinny-thin-high-body-fat-percentage/) if you need to.

Thanks for your help - Tara

```
.title h2 {
margin:10px 0 0 0;
width:780px;
font-family: HarabaraHandItalic;
font-size: 30px;
padding: 0 0 0 15px;
color:#000;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width you're using is too wide. Try to make the width 750px for example. You'll see that it works fine!

Keep in mind that the padding will be added to the width of the element.
In your case the h2 element is 780px (width) + 15px (padding-left) = 795px.

Comment: Your right. Sorry, I was trying to match the title to the width of the text below but I guess 790px must have been the container size. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine here.

I suspect you are being confused about what `width` means. The property describes the **content width**. The padding (15px) and borders (0px) and margin (0) all appear *around* the width.

The container is only 670px wide anyway, so you probably don't want something that is 795px across (width plus padding) inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce both the "width" and the "font-size" to make it fit.

Or, if the font-size needs to stay the same, you need to reduce the amount of copy.